# Trigger Email Firebase Extension on modified Document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

How do i trigger the sending of an email when a document data is **modified** ?

[Trigger Email](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email) only composes and sends an email based on the contents of a document **written** to a Cloud Firestore collection but not modified

I can’t figure this one out…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From checking the [code](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/master/firestore-send-email/functions/src/index.ts#L335) we can see that the extension already processes all writes to the document:

```
export const processQueue = functions.handler.firestore.document.onWrite(
  ...
```

From looking a bit [further](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/blob/2ad23a74ab40d09bc45395fa31dfe596a5c94d4a/firestore-send-email/functions/lib/index.js#L249) it seems that the action the extension takes upon a write depends on the value of the `delivery.state` field in the document.

```
async function processWrite(change) {
  ...
  const payload = change.after.data() as QueuePayload;
  ...

  switch (payload.delivery.state) {
    case "SUCCESS":
    case "ERROR":
      return null;
    case "PROCESSING":
      if (payload.delivery.leaseExpireTime.toMillis() < Date.now()) {
        // Wrapping in transaction to allow for automatic retries (#48)
        return admin.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {
          transaction.update(change.after.ref, {
            "delivery.state": "ERROR",
            error: "Message processing lease expired.",
          });
          return Promise.resolve();
        });
      }
      return null;
    case "PENDING":
    case "RETRY":
      // Wrapping in transaction to allow for automatic retries (#48)
      await admin.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {
        transaction.update(change.after.ref, {
          "delivery.state": "PROCESSING",
          "delivery.leaseExpireTime": admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromMillis(
            Date.now() + 60000
          ),
        });
        return Promise.resolve();
      });
      return deliver(payload, change.after.ref);
  }
}
```

My guess is that if you clear that field, the extension will pick up on that change and try to mail the document again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer Frank ! - So if I perform those changes in the code is there a way for me to deploy this updated version of the extension to use in my Firebase ? How ? : )

Comment: You shouldn't have to change the code of the extension, I merely included that to show you what the extension does. All you should need to do is change/delete the `delivery.state` of the document as far as I can tell. Did you try that?

Comment: Oh thanks so much ! Indeed I just had to switch delivery.state from "SUCCESS" to "RETRY" for it to resend - you're amazing Puff ! : )